# Random dice pictures

Tags: random, timer, picturebox, vb.net-2010

What is the code for randomizing the 6 faces of dice in the Picturebox. If I click the roll button the 6 pictureboxes will be randomize. Using the timer. What is the code in the timer. Please help. I'm a beginner and I don't know how to random pictureboxes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before getting into the code, you need to do some steps,  and i will show you these steps within pictures so it will be easier on you.

**1.Add all the faces of the dice as images in the 'Resources' tab.**

[image: PIC-1]

[image: PIC-2]

**2.The design :**

Add to your design a timer (Timer1), a button (Button1), a picturebox (Picturebox1).

**3.The code :**

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Rnd As New Random
    Dim FaceX, X As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Timer1.Stop()
        If X = 10 Then 'Note : 10 is the number of shuffling the images.
            X = 0
        Else
            FaceX = Rnd.Next(1, 7)
            If FaceX = 1 Then
                PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.DiceFace_1  'Note : replace [DiceFace_1] with the name of the image of the face1 of the dice that you added it in the Resources, and do that to all the coming commands....
            ElseIf FaceX = 2 Then
                PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.DiceFace_2
            ElseIf FaceX = 3 Then
                PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.DiceFace_3
            ElseIf FaceX = 4 Then
                PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.DiceFace_4
            ElseIf FaceX = 5 Then
                PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.DiceFace_5
            ElseIf FaceX = 6 Then
                PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.DiceFace_6
            End If
            X += 1
            Timer1.Start()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```